# How to again recheck the checkbox after deleting some item on btn click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a datalist in have I have checkbox, I am selecting the checkbox in client side using jquery, based on that checkbox selection I am deleting the item, few Item is not getting deleted as there is an instance in some other table, the items which is not deleted I want to show checkbox as check and error msg show that Selected item can't be deleted.

after deleting the item I am getting the not deleted Item ID but how to again check the checkbox based on that id.

on deleted btn

```
  foreach (DataListItem dl in dltlist1.Items)
        {
            if ((((CheckBox)dl.FindControl("Chkbox")).Checked))
            {
                ImageButton img = (dl.FindControl("btn1") as ImageButton);
                string[] str = img.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);
                IdList.Add(Id);
            }
        }
List<Tuple<int, int>> x = objBAL.Delete(IdList);
Tuple<int, int> temp = new Tuple<int, int>(item.Key, 1); // I am getting here non deleted key
```

after deleting the item I am binding the datalist again.

plz some one help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebinding the DataList you can loop through the DataList items and match the non deleted keys with the **DataKey** and if you find a match you can recheck the Checkbox.

**Example:**

```
         //here ArrayList contains the ids to match
         ArrayList a=new ArrayList();
         a.Add(201105);
         a.Add(201106);
         //loop through the items in the datalist
         for (int i = 0; i < DataList1.Items.Count;i++ )
         {
             //check if the list contains the items 
             if (a.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.DataKeys[i])))
             {
                 (DataList1.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked = true;
             }
         }
```

Any collection or generic that has .Contains() method would be ideal for this.

hope this helps.